# Non-parametric estimator of the joint distribution of two random variables where one is right-censored

Tags: distributions, estimation, survival, joint-distribution, censoring

I have 2-D samples of two continuous, correlated random variables where one of them is right-censored. I would like to estimate their joint distribution function using some non-parametric estimator. Any pointers to the literature or code/packages would be highly appreciated.